# Android: HERE map positioning manager getposition() always return Lat: 17976931348623200..,Lon: 17976931348623200

Tags: android, here-api

I am new to HERE maps currently trying to get current user location from Positioning manager , getlocation() method, but my code always return below information

com.nokia.maps.GeoPositionImpl[coordinate=GeoCoordinate [Latitude=-179769313486232000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000 Longitude=-179769313486232000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000 Altitude=1073741824.000000 Valid=FALSE]]

Below is my code:

```
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            //requestPermissions();

            // Search for the Map Fragment
            final MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment)
                    getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment);
    // initialize the Map Fragment and
    // retrieve the map that is associated to the fragment
            mapFragment.init(new OnEngineInitListener() {
                @Override
                public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(
                        OnEngineInitListener.Error error) {
                    if (error == OnEngineInitListener.Error.NONE) {
    // now the map is ready to be used
                        map = mapFragment.getMap();

                        onMapFragmentInitializationCompleted();
      } else {
                        System.out.println("ERROR: Cannot initialize MapFragment");
                        System.out.println("ERROR: Cannot initialize Map Fragment: " + error.toString());
                    }
                }
            });

       }




     private void onMapFragmentInitializationCompleted() {
            PositioningManager posManager;
             MapContainer placesContainer = null;
            // retrieve a reference of the map from the map fragment
           // map = mapFragment.getMap();
            // start the position manager
            posManager = PositioningManager.getInstance();
            posManager.start(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS_NETWORK);

            GeoPosition position = posManager.getPosition();
            GeoCoordinate cor = position.getCoordinate();

            // Set a pedestrian friendly map scheme
            map.setMapScheme(Map.Scheme.PEDESTRIAN_DAY);

            // Display position indicator
            map.getPositionIndicator().setVisible(true);

            placesContainer = new MapContainer();
            map.addMapObject(placesContainer);

            // Set the map center coordinate to the current position
            map.setCenter(posManager.getPosition().getCoordinate(), Map.Animation.NONE);
            map.setZoomLevel(14);
        }


Manifest.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.benz.event.navigation">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="navigation"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data android:name="com.here.android.maps.appid" android:value="MY ID"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.here.android.maps.apptoken" android:value="MY TOKEN"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.here.android.maps.license.key" android:value="MY KEY"/>



        <!--
           Embed the HERE Map Service.
          For more information, see the HERE SDK Developer's Guide
      -->
        <service
            android:name="com.here.android.mpa.service.MapService"
            android:label="HereMapService"
            android:process="global.Here.Map.Service.v2"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.here.android.mpa.service.MapService" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>



    </application>





</manifest>
```

Any help/hint will save my day

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Valid=FALSE Implies your device does not have a GPS lock. Is your device indoors and unable to obtain a position? Second, please check to see if your application has the positioning permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION " />
```

Comment: Thank you David for your response,Results are same with both indoor and outdoor scenarios (positioning in my google app is working as expected so i assume it might not be device problem)  and I  already have necessary permissions added in my manifest , Still no luck

Comment: What is the SDK target that you build the application with? I see in your code snippet you commented out requestPermissions() this implies the app is using the old permission model?

Comment: Details are: Complied version:compileSdkVersion 25 :: buildToolsVersion "25.0.0" :: minSdkVersion 15 ::  targetSdkVersion 22 , Currently i am using Asus p01z tablet which has Android 5.0.2 API 21 in it, is this an issue?

Comment: No, that should be OK because your target SDK is 22, the permission model is not there. Also your device is 5.o.x which does not use the new permission models. The device seems to have a GPS so I would imagine it to work. Can you please try to install the "HereWeGo" application from the store and see if positioning is working? Our consumer application uses the same SDK.

Comment: I have installed "HereWeGo" and everything is working as expected, i can see current location, so this makes it clear that there is something wrong within my code. I have few questions 1) Do i need to enable anything related to positioning in my API Account? 2) Is it necessary that i should implement custom position listener (currently i am working with basic positioning as you can see in my code?) 3) positioningmananger.getpostion() is called even before map is loaded completely in my device, So do i have to implement any maploadedcallback like in GoogleMaps(I cannot find any in here maps)

Comment: Well, your code snippet calls start and then immediately calls get position. It takes some time to start up GPS on the android device and receive the first position. I would assume after a few seconds your app will receive a valid position if you added a positioning manager listener.

Comment: I tired to implement position listener unfortunately on location update method is never called, i am wondering whats happening in my case. can you please redirect me to a working sample code as i see no reason why code doesnt work

Comment: https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/blob/master/3d-venues-and-indoor-routing/app/src/main/java/com/here/android/example/venue/Venue3dActivity.java